# Extracting data with celery and beautifulsoup

Tags: django, beautifulsoup, python-requests, celery, extract

I'm extracting data of articles in a website and pars them in my db in a django project using celery and bs4.Here is article model:

**articles/model.py**

```
from django.db import models

from conduit.apps.core.models import TimestampedModel


class Article(TimestampedModel):
   slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
   title = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)

   description = models.TextField()
   body = models.TextField()

   # Every article must have an author. This will answer questions like "Who
   # gets credit for writing this article?" and "Who can edit this article?".
   # Unlike the `User` <-> `Profile` relationship, this is a simple foreign
   # key (or one-to-many) relationship. In this case, one `Profile` can have
   # many `Article`s.
   author = models.ForeignKey(
       'profiles.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles'
   )

   tags = models.ManyToManyField(
       'articles.Tag', related_name='articles'
   )

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title


class Comment(TimestampedModel):
   body = models.TextField()

   article = models.ForeignKey(
       'articles.Article', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE
   )

   author = models.ForeignKey(
       'profiles.Profile', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE
   )


class Tag(TimestampedModel):
   tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   slug = models.SlugField(db_index=True, unique=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.tag
```

**profile/model.py**

```
from django.db import models

from conduit.apps.core.models import TimestampedModel


class MyUser(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Profile(TimestampedModel):
   user = models.ForeignKey(
       MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE
   )

   bio = models.TextField(blank=True)


   image = models.URLField(blank=True)


   follows = models.ManyToManyField(
       'self',
       related_name='followed_by',
       symmetrical=False
   )

   favorites = models.ManyToManyField(
       'articles.Article',
       related_name='favorited_by'
   )

   def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username

   def follow(self, profile):
       """Follow `profile` if we're not already following `profile`."""
       self.follows.add(profile)

   def unfollow(self, profile):
       """Unfollow `profile` if we're already following `profile`."""
       self.follows.remove(profile)

   def is_following(self, profile):
       """Returns True if we're following `profile`; False otherwise."""
       return self.follows.filter(pk=profile.pk).exists()

   def is_followed_by(self, profile):
       """Returns True if `profile` is following us; False otherwise."""
       return self.followed_by.filter(pk=profile.pk).exists()

   def favorite(self, article):
       """Favorite `article` if we haven't already favorited it."""
       self.favorites.add(article)

   def unfavorite(self, article):
       """Unfavorite `article` if we've already favorited it."""
       self.favorites.remove(article)

   def has_favorited(self, article):
       """Returns True if we have favorited `article`; else False."""
       return self.favorites.filter(pk=article.pk).exists()
```

and here is the tasks which I added to extract data. I used this tutorial:
https://soshace.com/creating-real-time-api-with-beautiful-soup-and-django-rest-framework/

**articles/tasks.py**

```
from time import sleep
from celery import shared_task
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from .models import Article
from ..profiles.models import MyUser, Profile


@shared_task
def find_article():
    url = 'https://...'
    r = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    html = urlopen(r).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    stories = soup.find_all('div', {'class': [
       'col u-xs-size12of12 js-trackPostPresentation u-paddingLeft12 u-marginBottom15 u-paddingRight12 u-size6of12',
       'col u-xs-size12of12 js-trackPostPresentation u-paddingLeft12 u-marginBottom15 u-paddingRight12 u-size4of12']})
   for story in stories:
       title = story.find('h3').text if story.find('h3') else '-'
       description = story.find('div', {
           'class': 'u-fontSize18 u-letterSpacingTight u-lineHeightTight u-marginTop7 u-textColorNormal u-baseColor--textNormal'}).text if story.find(
           'div', {
               'class': 'u-fontSize18 u-letterSpacingTight u-lineHeightTight u-marginTop7 u-textColorNormal u-baseColor--textNormal'}) else '-'
       slug = story.find('a')['href'].split('/')[-1]
       author = story.find('a', {
           'class': 'ds-link ds-link--styleSubtle link link--darken link--accent u-accentColor--textNormal u-accentColor--textDarken'})[
           'href'].split('@')[-1]
       story_url = story.find('a')['href']
       story_page = Request(story_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
       story_html = urlopen(story_page).read()
       story_soup = BeautifulSoup(story_html, 'html.parser')
       sections = story_soup.find_all('section')
       for section in sections:
           body = section.find('p')
           tags = section.find('p')

       my_user = MyUser(username=author)
       my_user.save()
       my_user_profile = Profile(user=my_user.id)
       my_user_profile.save()
       Article.objects.create(
           slug=slug,
           title=title,
           description=description,
           body=body,
           author=my_user_profile.id,
           tags=tags
       )
       sleep(5)


find_article()
```

I get this error when I type in Terminal: celery -A "projectname" worker -l info(according to tutorial):

ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Profile.user" must be a "MyUser" instance.

I'm a beginner and I can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is trying to tell you that `Profile.user` must be an instance of your user class, `MyUser` and that you're setting it to an integer `1`. Looking through your code, you have the following line:

```
my_user_profile = Profile(user=my_user.id)
```

If you instantiate `Profile` with `user=my_user` or `user_id=my_user.id`, things should clear up.

Comment: Yes you are right but sorry I didn't understand what should I do to solve it?Could you please explain once more?

Comment: Sure, use `Profile(user=my_user)` or `Profile(user_id=my_user.id)`.

Comment: for both of them I get this: ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Article.author" must be a "Profile" instance.
I changed author=my_user_profile.id, to author=my_user_profile, and now it is:ValueError: "<Article:blahblah>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Comment: Cool. That latest error means you need to save the object before you can add it to another model's `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: I think this is because of deleting .id which is not correct. In fact I save the object as you can see.Actually with the ways I used above and the way you suggested, author has been saved in myuser table

Comment: The error is regarding trying to assign 1 or many `Article` model instances to an author before the article has been saved.